# Tooltip-like Functionality in UiApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to add tooltips to `Label`s in `UiApp`. I was thinking about [`MousOverHandler`s](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/label#addMouseOverHandler%28Handler%29) on each (important) Label, as there is no function like `Label.setTooltip()`.

Is there any way to implement this functionality? The only thing I can think of doing is:

1. Creating a hidden Label (eh, don't really want to)
2. Add a `MouseOverHandler` to the Label I want a tooltip on
3. Make the hidden Label visible in the event handler

I don't really like this solution - is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `Label.setTitle("tooltip text")` directly on your widget? (works also with other widgets of course)

I guess that's what you are looking for .

Basic example [testable here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxD1z__V1hAKBf849FNZI6i-d7G74ABoaeBfV4GZnAeYbKEoVc/exec) :

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var abs = app.createAbsolutePanel().setStyleAttributes({"background":"#FFA","padding":"60px"});
  var lab = app.createLabel('Hover your mouse over this label').setTitle('There it is !');
  app.add(abs.add(lab));
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Go figure, another *not-so-well-named* method (in my opinion, of course). I guess with all the time I spent reading the docs I immediately glanced over that method because it looked like what I would call the method that sets the text of the actual widget. Well, thanks again Serge. I guess next time I'll scrutinize the docs a bit more when I'm reading them :)